# How do you specify a direct path volume in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to sync a directory on my local machine to a docker container. I want to be able to read and modify a directory on my local machine from a docker container and those changes be seen on the local machine. Adding a relative path in the volumes section of the docker-compose.yml file works, but a direct path does not. Here is what I have

```
volumes:
      - ../../logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

but what I want to do is

```
volumes:
     - /Users/bob/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

Comment: What is your host OS?  If you're using Docker Desktop on MacOS or Windows, do you need to add a path to the application's file-sharing configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your logs directory on your local machine and `pwd` to see if you have mistyped the absolute path.